Wifi stopped working overnight on Kubuntu 22.04
I have a laptop with Kubuntu 22.04 and yesterday I could connect to the wifi without issues but today I can't, it doesn't show any networks.
I've tried some suggestions online but with no success, this is what lshw shows
user@laptop:/etc/network$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED     
       description: wireless interface
       product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       producer: Ralink corp.
       . . .
       logical name: wlp3s0
       . . .
       capacities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=0.40 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

Any suggestions?
EDIT: To clarify, wifi can be activated and deactivated but always says there are 0 networks. In Kubuntu there's an option to set the wifi as an access point, when I click on it it throws an error as if it couldn't reach the wifi module or something.
EDIT2: My laptop has a key to enable/disable wifi, but does nothing (and also I don't think I've pressed it)
I've also tried sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager as a user suggested but didn't fix the issue.
EDIT3:
Some other commands I've run that I found on the internet in case they help somehow
user@laptop:/home/user$ sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scanning
wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

user@laptop:/home/user$ nmcli device

DEVICE      TYPE      STATE          CONNECTION          
enp4s0f2    ethernet  connected      Wired connection 1 
tailscale0  tun       connected      tailscale0          
wlp3s0      wifi      unavailable    --                  
lo          loopback  not handled    --

EDIT 3: As a user suggested in the comments, this is the output of the script to debug the networking issues https://termbin.com/2vql
EDIT 4: As stated in the comments, changing wifi.powersave to value 2 now makes it work for 1 minute, then a popup appears stating that the device is down. This is the output of nmcli device before the minute passes
user@laptop:~$ nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION          
enp4s0f2    ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1 
wlp3s0      wifi      connected               MyWifiNetwork1       
tailscale0  tun       connected (externally)  tailscale0          
lo          loopback  unmanaged               --                  

and after the minute passes
user@laptop:~$ nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION          
enp4s0f2    ethernet  connected               Wired connection 1    
tailscale0  tun       connected (externally)  tailscale0         
wlp3s0      wifi      disconnected            --     
lo          loopback  unmanaged               --                  

EDIT 5: This is the output of journalctl from boot until wifi disconnects https://termbin.com/ztrp

Likely a switch on it somewhere to disable the wifi

Already checked that, there is a wifi icon in the F2 key but didn't work, no matter if i pressed FN + F2 or CTRL + F2, doesn't seem to do anything.

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

@petep I've now tried that command, but still no luck. I've updated the question with more things that i've tried

In terminal run wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/jeremyb31/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info enter your password and choose y when asked if you want to upload results, post URL from terminal here.  This script is just an updated version of the one from https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Hello @Jeremy31, this is the output of the script you mentioned. I've updated my question also https://termbin.com/2vql . It's worth mentioning that I've censored some personal wifi access point names and IP addresses, just in case

In terminal sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and then sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off then reboot

OMG! That worked!! Thanks a million!! I'll mark this as the answer once you write it as such :) Btw, if you could please elaborate on why this fixed the issue, that'd be great because i really want to understand :( I assume it ha something to do with power saving options, but I don't know how did i end up setting that on? It's so weird :(
EDIT: Sorry to be a killjoy, but apparently it worked for 5 minutes, and the wifi networks disappeared again. Should I run the script again and send you the results? It's so weird

Just to add more info since it doesn't let me further update my above comment, every time I restart i get as i said 5 minutes or so of working wifi (it shows networks and updates the status it even connects to one of the known networks) then a popup appears saying that the wifi has disconnected and all networks disappear, all with me doing nothing but staring at the wifi networks panel. So weird :(

I've run journalctl in case it helps somehow https://termbin.com/ztrp from boot to wifi failure

In the end I bought a cheap USB wifi dongle to fix this, and it works nicely.
